# SilverStripe images are not visible in frontend ! Only logged user can see those images

Tags: silverstripe

Silver stripe images are not being displayed on frontend the images are visible only if we login

In dashboard it have to the file permission option i made to form logged user int anyone but still the same issue.

Any help will be appriciated !

Thanks!

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the problem is here. Please provide more information about your setup. Do you run SilverStripe 4?

Comment: Im running SilverStripe-cms-v4.0.0-rc3



Thanks!

Comment: With SilverStripe 4, files are also versioned… you need to publish files first, before they will show up in your site.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the images need to be published individually of the pages they are in causing headaches. If you add $owns it will cause the images to update/publish when you publish the page itself, the way it should be by default in my opinion.

```
private static $has_one = [
    'TeaserImage'=>Image::Class
    //This is my image for the page.
];
private static $owns = [
    'TeaserImage'
    //Adding this will make sure the image is published with the page.
];
```